# Why is my slide down navigation not working in specific window width

Tags: jquery, css, media-queries, css-animations, conditional-statements

I have a `div`element in my header - which I am using as my navigation bar - that is full width (i.e.: `width: 100%;` ) and I'm using CSS and jQuery to make it behave different ways for different devices.

The basic structure of the navigation bar is as so:

```
        <div id="nav-bar" class="bar">

            <div id="nav-content" class="cf">

                <div id="branding-wrap">
                    <a href="homeurl"><img src="/images/logo.png" id="logo"></a>
                </div><!-- End #branding-wrap -->

                <nav id="main-nav" class="right">

                    <?php 

                        get_search_form();

                        wp_nav_menu(array(
                            'menu' => 'Main Nav Menu',
                            'container_class' => 'menu-item'
                        )); 
                    ?>
                </nav>

                <a href="#mobile-nav"><img src="/images/menu.png" id="menu-icon" class="left"></a>
            </div><!-- End #nav-content -->
        </div><!-- End #nav-bar -->
```

The `div` has a class `.bar` that is styled as follows:

```
.bar {
top:                -67px;
width:              100%;
opacity:            0.97;
z-index:            30;
position:           fixed;
border-bottom:      solid 1px #2B292B;
background-color:   #FCFCFC;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
-moz-box-shadow:    0px 2px 4px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
box-shadow:         0px 2px 4px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
-webkit-transition: top 0.4s;
-moz-transition:    top 0.4s;
-ms-transition:     top 0.4s;
-o-transition:      top 0.4s;
transition:         top 0.4s;}
```

I use the following if statement to target desktops and tablets, and apply the class `.slideDown` to the navigation bar, changing it's position from `top: -67px;` to `top: 0;`:

```
    var offset = $(window).scrollTop();

    if($(window).width() > 659 && offset > 10 ){

        $('#nav-bar').addClass('slideDown');

    }else{

        $('#nav-bar').removeClass('slideDown');
    }
```

For mobile devices I have the following media query: `@media only screen and (max-width:659px){}`. And, for screens that fall under this width I have simply changed the styling of the navigation bar like so:

```
.bar {
    top: 0;
}
```

Unfortunately, I have found that if the screen width falls between 676px and 659px, the `.slideDown` class is never added to `#nav-bar` and the width of `#nav-bar` breaks out of its parent element (which is also given 100% width) - at first I thought this was due to giving both the parent and child elements 100% widths, but this overflow only occurs between 676px and 659px.

It appears my CSS and jQuery have a blindspot, so to speak, but there's no gap between where one drops off, and the other picks up.

My other media query is also picks up right after the aforementioned one (`@media only screen and (min-width:660px) and (max-width:979px){}`) and neither `.bar` nor `.slideDown` are used as selectors in this media query.

I also checked Chrome Dev Tools and couldn't find any conflicting styles it might have inherited.

Why is jQuery not adding the specified class to `#nav-bar`, and why is `#nav-bar` breaking out of its parent, between 659 px and 676 px?

Comment: what did you use the `offset > 10` in `if($(window).width() > 659 && offset > 10 ){` for? What style is inside class `slideDown`? Did your page have any scrollbar? Also can you reproduce the problem either using [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or using the `Snippet`

Comment: I used it to get the navigation bar to slide down once the user scrolls down. slideDown simply has "top: 0". I created a JSFiddle, but I don't see how you can get the width of the "result" pane to the right size to replicate the issue. https://jsfiddle.net/n3vx8hs9/

Comment: when did you call the function that add/removeClass `slideDown`? Is it on window resize/scroll/else?

Comment: When the user scrolls down, the navigation bar appears to slide down, for widths greater than 659px. For screen widths 659px or smaller "div.bar" top property is set to 0.

Comment: no, I mean when did the function run? Is it only run once on document ready, or it trigger every time the user scroll or the windows resized?

Comment: The function runs when the user scrolls down, and when the user scrolls up, as long as the width of their window is more than 659px. Otherwise, the function does not run.

Comment: has my answer help solved your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the problem that you get.
The `CSS` style

```
@media only screen and (max-width:659px){}
```

will calculate the `max-width` of the window screen including the `scrollbar`, but when you call

```
$(window).width()
```

it will return the width of the window screen excluding the `scrollbar`, there what caused you to have unexpected results when your window screen (including the `scrollbar` if you check it using the `Chrome developer tools`) width is between `659px` & `676px`.

What you need to do is to use the `CSS` as your base to define if it width is `> 659px` or not by adding some `style` to the `@media only screen and (max-width:659px){}`, in your case I was changing the `z-index` from `30` to `35` to detect if the `CSS` has defined that the `width` is already `< 660px`

Then using the `jQuery`, you need to check whether the `z-index` CSS value of class `.bar` is `30` (which means that the width is > 659px) or `35` (which mean the other), then use it as the conditional if rather than using the `$(window).width()`.

Here's the working example from your example:

```js
$(window).on('scroll', function () {
    var offset = $(window).scrollTop();
    if ($('.bar').css('z-index') == '30' && offset > 10) {
        $('#nav-bar').addClass('slideDown');
    } else {
        $('#nav-bar').removeClass('slideDown');
    }
});
```

```css
ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.bar {
  top: -67px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 67px;
  opacity: 0.97;
  z-index: 30;
  position: fixed;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #2B292B;
  background-color: #FCFCFC;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -webkit-transition: top 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: top 0.4s;
  -ms-transition: top 0.4s;
  -o-transition: top 0.4s;
  transition: top 0.4s;
}
.slideDown {
  top: 0;
}
body {
  height: 1500px;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 659px) {
  .bar {
    top: 0;
    z-index: 35;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="nav-bar" class="bar">
    <div id="nav-content" class="cf">
        <div id="branding-wrap"> <a href="homeurl"><img src="/images/logo.png" id="logo"/></a>

        </div>
        <!-- End #branding-wrap -->
        <nav id="main-nav" class="right">
            <ul>
                <li>menu-item</li>
                <li>menu-item</li>
                <li>menu-item</li>
            </ul>
        </nav> <a href="#mobile-nav"><img src="/images/menu.png" id="menu-icon" class="left"/></a>

    </div>
    <!-- End #nav-content -->
</div>
<!-- End #nav-bar -->
```

**Note**: Click the `Full Page` so you can resize the window width